# Getting $area from a feature in a processing script in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-processing, area

I've created a complex process, but I'm stuck on one point.
I found this code to find the number of features in a layer.

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    input_featuresource = self.parameterAsSource(parameters,
                                                 'INPUT',
                                                 context)
    numfeatures = input_featuresource.featureCount()
```

However for my computations I need the area from the one feature that is the input-layer and I can't find any code to do this. Using Python directly I would use something like this:

```
features = layer.getFeatures()
for f in features:
    geom = f.geometry()
    print "Area:", geom.area()
```

But is this possible in a processing script?
What is the best way of obtaining the area-value I need?

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer. By using this code I was able to obtain the area of the feature.

```
source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, 'INPUT', context)
features = source.getFeatures()
for f in features:
    geom=f.geometry()
    opp=geom.area()
```